# ANTLR: token recognized as rule, instead of type

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following very simple ANTLR grammer:

```
SPACE                    : [ ]+ -> skip;
NUMBER                   : ('0'..'9')+;

event                    : '1' '|' identifier EOF;
identifier               : NUMBER;
```

The idea is to parse all inputs of format `1 | <number>`.

This works fine for for example the input `1 | 50`. But it fails for `1 | 1`. I believe I understand what is going on: the second `1` is recognized as the rule `event` and not the rule `identifier`, but I am not sure how to fix this.

How do I proceed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the literal `'1'` in a parser rule, ANTLR will implicitly create a lexer rule for this. So the rules:

```
event                    : '1' '|' identifier EOF;
NUMBER                   : ('0'..'9')+;
```

are really this:

```
event                    : T_0 T_1 identifier EOF;
T_0                      : '1';
T_1                      : '|';
NUMBER                   : ('0'..'9')+;
```

And ANTLR's lexer will always create tokens in the following way:

1. try to match as much characters as possible for each lexer rule
2. whenever there are 2 or more lexer rules that match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

So, for the input `1`, the token `T_0` will always be created (point 2 applies). And for the input `11` the token `NUMBER` will always be created (point 1 applies).

In other words: the input `1` will never become a `NUMBER` token. If you want that, do something like this:

```
SPACE                    : [ ]+ -> skip;
ONE                      : '1';
NUMBER                   : ('0'..'9')+;

event                    : ONE '|' identifier EOF;
identifier               : number;
number                   : ONE | NUMBER;
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes completely sense. So basically, I first define my tokens (such as `1`). Then I define "general" types, such as `NUMBER: ('0'..'9')+`. Finally, in my rules, I do not forget to include the tokens as well, as they might be a subset of some generic type.

Comment: You're welcome. Always make sure the "more important" rules (like `1`) are placed _before_ other rules that might also match your important ones.

Comment: Got it! Thanks you.